# Convert C Union to C# (Incorrectly Aligned)

Tags: c#, c, winapi, pinvoke

I want to call the [DhcpGetClientInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API from C# but I have a question on conversion of this C struct to C#:

```
typedef struct _DHCP_CLIENT_SEARCH_INFO {
  DHCP_SEARCH_INFO_TYPE SearchType;
  union {
    DHCP_IP_ADDRESS ClientIpAddress;
    DHCP_CLIENT_UID ClientHardwareAddress;
    LPWSTR          ClientName;
  } SearchInfo;
} DHCP_SEARCH_INFO, *LPDHCP_SEARCH_INFO;
```

I think the Correct conversion is this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=12)]
public struct DHCP_SEARCH_INFO
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public DHCP_SEARCH_INFO_TYPE SearchType;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public DHCP_IP_ADDRESS ClientIpAddress;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public DHCP_BINARY_DATA ClientHardwareAddress;
    [FieldOffset(4), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string ClientName;
};
```

But that gives an System.TypeLoadException: Additional information: Could not load type 'Dhcpsapi.DHCP_SEARCH_INFO' from assembly 'ConsoleApplication3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 4 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.

This is the conversion of the other types in case you want to compile:

```
public enum DHCP_SEARCH_INFO_TYPE : uint
{
    DhcpClientIpAddress = 0,
    DhcpClientHardwareAddress = 1,
    DhcpClientName = 2
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DHCP_BINARY_DATA
{
    public uint DataLength;
    public IntPtr Data;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DHCP_IP_ADDRESS
{
    public UInt32 IPAddress;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I verified sizeof and offsets in C:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"Dhcpsapi.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DHCP_SEARCH_INFO si;

    printf("sizeof(DHCP_SEARCH_INFO)=%d\n", sizeof(DHCP_SEARCH_INFO));

    printf("ClientIpAddress offset=%d\n", (PBYTE)&si.SearchInfo.ClientIpAddress - (PBYTE)&si);
    printf("ClientHardwareAddress offset=%d\n", (PBYTE)&si.SearchInfo.ClientHardwareAddress - (PBYTE)&si);
    printf("ClientName offset=%d\n", (PBYTE)&si.SearchInfo.ClientName - (PBYTE)&si);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
sizeof(DHCP_SEARCH_INFO)=12
ClientIpAddress offset=4
ClientHardwareAddress offset=4
ClientName offset=4
```

**EDIT:**
Based on Camford's answer I declared the struct as below. Using sizeof should make it correct for x64 as well.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=12)]
public struct DHCP_SEARCH_INFO
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public DHCP_SEARCH_INFO_TYPE SearchType;
    [FieldOffset(sizeof(DHCP_SEARCH_INFO_TYPE))]
    public DHCP_IP_ADDRESS ClientIpAddress;
    [FieldOffset(sizeof(DHCP_SEARCH_INFO_TYPE))]
    public IntPtr ClientName;
    [FieldOffset(sizeof(DHCP_SEARCH_INFO_TYPE))]
    public DHCP_BINARY_DATA ClientHardwareAddress;
};
```

Comment: Did you try `static_assert(sizeof(DHCP_SEARCH_INFO)==12, "No wonder it doesn't work.");` ?

Comment: @Lundin: I checked in C: sizeof(DHCP_SEARCH_INFO) == 12, that's why I added the Size=12

Comment: public class DHCP_IP_ADDRESS Are you sure you didn't mean struct?

Comment: @Camford: Thanks for spotting that, should indeed be struct! Doesn't solve my problem though (edited)

Comment: Is the exception thrown in a 32 bit or 64 bit process? You have pointers in the structure and in 64 bit these should be aligned on an 8 byte boundary, not 4 as in 32 bit.

Comment: @MartinLiversage: x86 (also tried to use FieldOffset(sizeof(uint)))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way you are simulating the union is correct as far as I can tell. The exception you are getting is likely related to the`string` object in your struct. I tried to build your code in a test project. With string in the struct, I get the same exception as you do. With an IntPtr replacing the string, I don't get any exceptions. Whether the call to `DhcpGetClientInfo` is going to work or not, I have no idea. You can use [`Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobaluni.aspx) to get an IntPtr for your string.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct SearchInfo
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public DHCP_IP_ADDRESS ClientIpAddress;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public DHCP_BINARY_DATA ClientHardwareAddress;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public IntPtr ClientName; //LPWSTR
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DHCP_SEARCH_INFO
{
    public DHCP_SEARCH_INFO_TYPE SearchType;
    public SearchInfo SearchInfo;
}
```

Edit: I guess this means that simulating a union in C# has similar requirement to the union in C++. In C++ you can only have POD types in a union. In C# you can probably only have struct types.

Updated: Thanks to DavidHeffernan for pointing out a better way of laying out structs with unions inside. You can read his explanation below.

Comment: I tested this and it's working, the MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWSTR) should be left out though.

Comment: This is a poor way to implement a union. Because it forces you to define field offsets for all fields. Which is messy and no fun at all if your code is AnyCPU! The best way to do it is to define a separate struct purely for the union. And use explicit layout for that with field offset 0 for all members. And then include that struct in the containing struct which you can declare as sequential. I'm happy to show some example code if you are interested.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for the information. I'll update the answer when I get home later.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry for being late to the party, but I did as you suggested (sequential struct containing a field which itself is an explicit struct) and all I get is a `TypeLoadException`, claiming `Cannot marshal field 'ExplicitStruct' of type 'My.Assembly.SequentialStruct` and `The type definition of this field has layout information but has an invalid managed/unmanaged type combination or is unmarshalable`. May I therefore ask you to fulfill your offer back in the days and show some (preferable extensive) example code? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best thing to do is to add get/set methods to... guess what... get/set the correct bits in a variable. I believe that you'll have to wrap that too

Something like:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DHCP_SEARCH_INFO
{
    public DHCP_SEARCH_INFO_TYPE SearchType;
    public ulong Complex;
};

public struct DHCP_SEARCH_INFO_WRAP
{
   public DHCP_SEARCH_INFO_TYPE SearchType;
   private ulong Complex;

   public DHCP_IP_ADDRESS ClientIpAddress
   {
     get
     {
         return BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(Complex),0);
     }
     set
     {
         byte[] orig = BitConverter.GetBytes(Complex);
         byte[] chng = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
         Array.Copy(chng,0,orig,0,4);

     }
   }
   public DHCP_SEARCH_INFO_WRAP(ref DHCP_SEARCH_INFO var)
   {
      this.SearchType = var.SearchType;
      this.Complex = var.Complex;

   }

};
```

I wrote this directly here and didn't test it.

EDIT: 
Camford enlightened me that you can have unions in C#, I was wrong. But as it seem that you can only emulate the primitive types I stand by my solution

Comment: Was just typing up something similar (though I used a 8 byte array instead of a ulong).  This kind of approach should work.

Comment: `LayoutKind.Explicit` exists so that you can simulate a union in C#.

Comment: @Camford Yeah, I just checked it out. I tried to write unions like that in the past but failed and ended up using the approach I am proposing, must have been objects in those unions I was trying to emulate since that seems to be the problem